# How do I get the wolfram cdf player to work in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, wolfram-alpha

I wanted to be able to edit and look at stuff like this on wolfram,
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HypothesisTestsAboutAPopulationMean/

So I downloaded the wolfram cdf player but I don't know how to use it on chrome because after installing the software the website still thinks I don't have the cdf player and is asking me to download it?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but does it work with other browsers?

Comment: @simon it works on internet explorer after some research I don't think it works on chrome anymore

Comment: Yep. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67540/34